# list index out of range an if statement that's in a for loop

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, if-statement

I am web scraping with selenium for articles but there are some ads there from the site which don't contain text. So I cant scrape the text because it doesn't have any. So I thought I could use an if statement but it still gives the error. How can I fix this?

heres the code:

```
for i in range(10):
    dict1 = {}
    driver.get("https://www.vrt.be/vrtnws/nl/rubrieken/economie/")
    sleep(1)

    articles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("vrt-teaser__title-text")
    a = articles[i].text
    articles[i].click()
    sleep(1)
    if driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cmp-text")[0].text and driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cmp-text")[1].text:
        tupletext = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cmp-text")[0].text, driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cmp-text")[1].text
    else:
        a = "None"
        tupletext = "None"
    dict1 = a, tupletext
    csv_writer.writerow([a,tupletext])
    print(dict1)
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: It's not recommended to chain variable access: `var1.var2.var3` should be `temp = var1.var2 temp.var3` with appropriate names of course. Also include the error details so we can assist you better

Comment: I don't understand, do u mean in the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

you can use try...except like this:

```
try:
        tupletext = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cmp-text")[0].text, driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cmp-text")[1].text
except:
        a = "None"
        tupletext = "None"
```

Basically, it runs the command, and if the command returns an error, it goes to the 'except' block and assign None to a and tupletext.

Comment: It's called flow by exceptions, which is considered bad practice

Comment: In this particular situation, what risks does it represent?

Comment: risks? what do u mean

Answer (score 0):

Your error is list *index out of range*, so your `if` statement should be:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cmp-text")
if (elements.len() < 2) // process an empty tuple
else // normal tuple
```